# play sound with text fadein

Tags: jquery, text, audio, mp3, jplayer

What is the best way to play a short bell sound every time the texts in my below code fade in?

I read that jplayer is perhaps the best option?

I have tried jquery.sound but in Firefox it causes the "install plugin" box to appear infinitely if there is no Quicktime installed.

```
$(function(){
  $(window).mousemove(function(){
    runIt();
  });
  runIt();      
})

function runIt() {
  var it = $('#myText');
  it.stop(true,true).clearQueue().fadeOut(1).animate({left:0},500).queue(function(){
    it.html('Start Again');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(500).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 1');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 2');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 3');
    $(window).unbind('mousemove');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Well, to begin with; that code looks really inefficient. Not really sure what you are doing with this since it was taken out of context, so would be nice if you could show us as a little more.

Anyway, to try and answer your question HTML5 has [native support for audio playback](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/video.html#htmlmediaelement) but maybe you need a solution that's more cross-browser friendly?

With HTML5 you only have to do this:

```
var sample = new Audio("file.mp3");
sample.play();
```

Personally I wouldn't go with any other solution and leave it silent if the browser doesn't support HTML5 audio.

Edit: I read the code a bit closer and realized you are clearing/stopping the queue at places. Not sure about triggering it on every little move of the mouse though :)

Edit 2: I took the liberty to play around a bit with your code and jPlayer (which uses HTML5 audio if possible) and ended up with this:

```
$(function() {

    var element = $('#myText'),
        jPlayer = $("#jPlayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    wav: "http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/multimedia/pc-sounds/ding.wav"
                });
            },
            supplied: "wav"
        });

    function jPlay() {   
        jPlayer.jPlayer("stop").jPlayer("playHead", 0).jPlayer("play");
    }

    function runIt() {
        element
            .stop(true, true)
            .clearQueue()
            .fadeOut(1)
            .animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500)
            .queue(function() {
                jPlay();
                element
                    .html('Start Again')
                    .dequeue();
            })
            .fadeIn(500)
            .animate({
                left: 0
            }, 5000)
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .queue(function() {
                jPlay();
                element
                    .html('test 1')
                    .dequeue();
            })
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .animate({
                left: 0
            }, 5000)
            .fadeOut(1000).queue(function() {
                jPlay();
                element
                    .html('test 2')
                    .dequeue();
            })
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .animate({
                left: 0
            }, 5000)
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .queue(function() {
                jPlay();
                $(window).unbind('mousemove');
                element
                    .html('test 3')
                    .dequeue();
            })
            .fadeIn(1000);
    }
    $(window).mousemove(function() {
        //runIt();
    });
    runIt();
});
```

You can [try this out at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/P78L6/)

Comment: @Marcus hi thanks for the response. Yes something cross-browser compatible would be good. I tried the solution above and it works but for some reason the sound playback is choppy (not smooth) and it only works if the file is a .wav. I'm not sure why?

Comment: @Sarah, doesn't work for all formats. What audio type are you trying to playback?

Comment: how big is the wav file? MP3 has to be encoded with a fair CBR that is standard to Media Player for eg.

Comment: @ppumkin it's just a small file - 61kb

Comment: @Marcus i don't mind really. I just thought mp3 might be quicker to load as it's 31kb but the wav option is only 61 so not too bad I guess. Not sure why it is so choppy though. Is it maybe the fadein affecting it? Because it seems to chop and the fade in chops a little too at the same time...

Comment: @Sarah, I've updated my answer with an example based on your code. It uses jsPlayer and should be quite cross-browser friendly. Hope you'll find it useful! :)